# How can i add selected=selected to save my dropdown if there is an error in my form?

Tags: javascript, php

I have two php files one is a class my_class
has a function in it called dropit()

this function looks like

```
@res = DataBase::database("select id, name,image from product");
echo "<option value="0">Select one</option>";
if($res){
    foreach($res as $value){
        echo "<option value='{$value[id]}' data-image='{$value['image']}'>{$value['name']} -- {$value['id']}</option>"
    }
}
echo "</select>"
```

then in my index php i have a drop down that is populated using

```
<?php my_class::dropit(); ?>
```

if there is a error in my form i would like the dropdown to stay on the selected item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if your select value is in `$_POST` and while in your `foreach()` loop check to see if it matches the current value.

```
@res = DataBase::database("select id, name,image from product");
echo "<option value="0">Select one</option>";
if($res){
    foreach($res as $value){
        $selected = isset($_POST['nameofyourselect']) && $_POST['nameofyourselect'] == $value[id]) ? " selected='selected'" : "";
        echo "<option value='{$value[id]}' data-image='{$value['image']}'{$selected}>{$value['name']} -- {$value['id']}</option>"
    }
}
echo "</select>"
```

Comment: i have copied this almost identically i forgot to put the  ' ' in my id parameter above and it looks like you copied that mistake too  so fixed that but does not seem to work when i echo the $_POST['employee'] it shows the value id on the main page but no selected='selected' is ever added and it dosent remain on a faild form